# How to find sequence of letters in a list of strings?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have the list:

```
lst1 = ['abc', 'abcde', 'abab', 'acd']
```

I want to create a dictionary to count the # of times 'ab' is in the list, so in this example, the dictionary would be `{'ab': 4}`. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator expression within `sum`

```
>>> lst1 = ['abc', 'abcde', 'abab', 'acd']
>>> {'ab': sum(i.count('ab') for i in lst1)}
{'ab': 4}
```

Comment: I think `{'ab': sum(i.count('ab') for i in lst1)}` would be preferable since it gives the desired answer of 4, plus it automatically handles the fact that the pattern could be not found in some elements of the list.

Comment: @elog Oh I see, I understand their goal now, they even want to count repetitions within a string, instead of just the total number of strings in their list that do/don't contain it

Comment: Yup! Just removed the ternary `if` also since `count()` takes care of it.

Comment: Good point, edited!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
>>> {'ab': ','.join(l).count('ab')}
{'ab': 4}
```